# how to split a long string into multiple variables

Tags: r

I have a df that contain long strings. If I want to separate it into different variable, how should I do that?

sample data is here:

```
df <- structure(list(tx = c(" [1]          Timepoint                                       EGTMPT      Categorical select one (nominal) 51         Screening", 
" [2]          N/A : O ff-Study                                EGTNA       Categorical yes/no (dichotomous) 3", 
" [3]          Check if Not Done                               EGTMPTND    Categorical yes/no (dichotomous) 3", 
" [4]          Date Performed                                  ECGDT       Date                             11", 
" [5]          Time (24-hour format)                           ECGTM       Time                             5", 
" [6]          O verall ECG Interpretation                     ECGRES      Categorical select one (nominal) 37         Normal"
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: use `separate` from `tidyr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the variables occupy a fixed space, so to find those spaces we do the following:

Manually separate one line:

```
vars = c(" [1]          ", "Timepoint                                       ", "EGTMPT      ",
         "Categorical select one (nominal) ", "51         ", "Screening")
```

Count the number of characters in each variable:

```
sizes = numeric(length(vars))

for(i in 1:length(vars)){
  sizes[i] = nchar(vars[i])}
```

Cumulatively sum those values and add a 1 (starting point) at the beggining:

```
sizes = c(1, cumsum(sizes))
```

The result is:

```
> sizes
[1]   1  14  62  74 107 118 127
```

So the first variable goes from the 1st to the 14th position, etc. Now we just need to cut each line in those places:

```
df2 = character()
for(i in 2:length(sizes)){
  df2 = cbind(df2, apply(df, 1, function(x){substr(x, sizes[i-1], sizes[i])}))}
```

And lastly remove the extra spaces:

```
df2 = gsub(" ", "", df2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. however it turned out it is not fix col size through the data.(sample data did not show that) So I am think replace `"   "` to`"  "` so I can not two empty space as cut off. Any suggestion on how to achieve that?

Comment: I understood your problem but not your suggestion, can you rephrase it please?

Comment: Well you can use pattern = " {1,}" which is a space 1 or more times, but the problem is that there is a column that is separated by only one space (`...(dichotomous) 3...`), and at the same time, strings that should not be separated that also have only one space `...Time (24-hour format)...`. So from my knowledge there is no applicable pattern to break your data up. Is this a dataset that you created? If yes then you can correct it in the moment of creation.